# How I can pass FormCollection object with $.ajax(...)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working C# MVC application and I have 2 action method in a controller:

```
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Save")]
public ActionResult SaveBasicInformation(FormCollection collection)
{.....}

[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Submit")]
public ActionResult SubmitRequest(FormCollection collection)
{....}
```

The above code is working fine without ajax request. Now my question is how i can to pass "FormCollection" in $.ajax(..) for specific controller method.

```
var input = $(':input');
     $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("SaveBasicInformation", "Home")',
         type: 'POST',
         cache: false,
         data: input,
         success: function (data) {
             alert("Success");
         },
         error: function (result) {
             alert("Error");
             alert(result.responseText);
         }
     });
```

Here is the error message when i use the above ajax code:

```
The current request for action 'SaveBasicInformatio'' on controller type HomeController' 
is ambiguous between the following action methods: System.Web.MVC.Action Result 
SubmitRrquest(System.Web.formCollection)....
```

Thank you for your help...

Comment: Have you tried removing the `[MultipleButton]` attribute from your action methods?

Comment: Yes.. After removing it's working fine.. Thank you so much for your help. I removed this attribute on all buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[MultipleButton]' attribute is a custom attribute [possibly from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework)? which may be causing the problem as its an ajax call. Try removing the attributes.